# Window prompt blocks code execution before it

Tags: javascript, prompt

I've got this code in javascript right before a `window.prompt()` function. However, the code preceding the prompt is obstructed by the prompt, even though it's before the `prompt()` function. For example, here's what I'm expecting to see:

```js
console.log('Hello World!');
const prompt = window.prompt(message, defaultText);
```

> Hello World!
>
> **PROMPT OPENS**

However, it does this:

```js
console.log('Hello World!');
const prompt = window.prompt('See how the console.log doesn\'t appear while this is open?', 'Yes, I do see that! Clicking Cancel or Ok then logs it!');
```

What causes this to happen? I'd understand if the `console.log` came after the prompt rather than before it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just how the browser runs the update cycle. The sleep waiting for the prompt blocks the render of the new content from firing.

Comment: But my code is ***BEFORE*** the prompt function; shouldn't it sleep the code after it?

Comment: Hopefully someone can post a link to a good answer on another question that explains how rendering/screen painting works.

Comment: No. `prompt()` just blocks the execution. [If the browser does the actual output later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync) then it's completely reasonable that you won't see the logs until the thread is unblocked.

Comment: So that means code before and after are blocked, creating the same behavior as if the prompt function was at the top?

Comment: No, it does not mean that. It means that *if the code on top* requires some interaction *that needs the current processing to finish*, then that interaction will be blocked. In the snippet here the log is "delayed" because it actually updates the DOM. And the DOM needs the UI thread to refresh. If you check the actual browser console you'd see `"Hello World!"` printed in both Firefox and Chrome even if you don't close the prompt box. Which is not what you see in the snippet, since the snippet uses a different way to show the log to a normal browser.

Comment: Can someone make this an answer so I can mark it as done?