# prompt executing before page full load and block the console.log

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, prompt

I have an interesting question.

I have a prompt in JS. When I go to my page prompt immediately executes and blocks the console.logs. After doing some logic in the prompt, when I close the prompt all the console.logs immediately shows in the console. And it happens only when i join in the page at the first time. Next time all console.logs work fine. I the problem, but i don't know solution. I assume it's how the browser, and js works. There is no solution here.

```js
let userAnswer = "";
let contvertedStr = "";

while (true) {
  const type = prompt(
    "Program – Main Menu \nPlease enter 1, 2, 3, or exit."
  ).toLowerCase();

  if (type === "1") {
    while (!userAnswer) {
      userAnswer = prompt("Please enter a string.");

      if (!userAnswer) {
        console.log("You need to enter something");
      }
    }
  }

  if (type === "2") {
    if (!userAnswer) {
      console.log("You need to first enter a String");
      continue;
    }

    const splitString = userAnswer.split(" ");
    let newArray = [];

    for (const str of splitString) {
      if (str.length >= 5) {
        newArray.push(str + "-bonk");
      } else {
        newArray.push(str + "-bink");
      }
    }

    contvertedStr = newArray.join(" ");

    console.log("String converted");
  }

  if (type === "3") {
    if (contvertedStr) {
      console.log(contvertedStr);

      userAnswer = "";
      contvertedStr = "";

      continue;
    } else {
      console.log("You need to first convert your String");
      continue;
    }
  }

  if (type === "exit") {
    console.log("Thanks for using the ROBOT Language Converter!");
    break;
  }
}
```

I triend DOMContentloaded, window.onload, async, defer etc. It didn't work

Comment: `window.prompt()` is a blocking operation.  The browser isn't exepcted to do *anything* while it's waiting on that.  This is expected behavior.

Comment: @David Okay, why second it works fine?

Comment: You've probably made a mistake or false assumption in your debugging.  `window.prompt()` is designed to be a blocking operation.  Perhaps you could update the question to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates specifically the behavior you're describing?

Comment: What console logs are you talking about? I see `You need to enter something` immediately after I give an empty response.

Comment: @David You can run by pressing the "Run code snippet" above and typing something.

Comment: @Danber: And when one does that, what specific observation are you referring to?

Comment: Note that the virtual log provided by Stack Snippet is delayed, but the real log in DevTools shows the messages immediately.

Comment: @Barmar No. execute the code. When type 1. When just press enter 3 times. When typing something and when typing "exit". Only after I'll see the logs

Comment: That's not what I see. I type 1, and each time I press enter it logs "You need to enter something".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71300629/window-prompt-blocks-code-execution-before-it You can check it here. @David

Comment: Then I enter `foo-bar-baz`. Next I enter `2` and it says `String converted`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in the other question, either. I see `Hello world!` in the Console while the prompt is open.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using the latest Chrome.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I`m also use latest chrome

Comment: Ultimately the takeaway here is *probably* a combination of: (1) Logging to the console may go into some background queue which may or may not be affected by blocking operations, for a related observation see the many duplicates about logging arrays and seeing incorrect data because the array was mutated. (2) Don't use blocking operations in the first place.  We've come a long way in the past 30 years, we don't really need `prompt` or `confirm` or `alert` much anymore.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/a3jGnT.jpg

Comment: I've never used them, but my wife has an assignment at university. Its stupid thing, but it had be done

Comment: The first time I executed the code in my browser, I didn't see any logs. I need to type "exit" when reload the page and only when I'll be able to see the logs correctly

Comment: Ah, @Barmar I saw your screenshot, try to copy and paste it to vs code or anything. And you'll understand me

Comment: I don't use the built-in consoles of IDEs, I test in real browsers.

Comment: It sounds like a VS Code issue, not a JavaScript problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while (true) {`

Unless used in say an `async` loop, this is never a good idea for Javascript, how the console behaves when the main Event loop is constantly blocked is likely undefined behaviour and should not be something you rely on.

Now there are 2 simple ways to solve this,

1. Use a `setTimeout` to continue the loop.
2. Use an `async` loop like pointed out above.

So for option 1 ->

```js
function doLoop() {
  const r = prompt('type x to quit').toLowerCase();
  console.log(`you typed ${r}`);
  if (r !== 'x') 
    setTimeout(doLoop);
}

doLoop();  //lets start the loop
```

So basically in the above we are just replacing `continue` with `setTimeout(doLoop)`, and removing the `while (true) {`

Now for option 2, using an `async` loop, this is the better option in the long run as it is much easier to expand on.

```js
const breath = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));

async function doLoop() {
  while (true) {
    await breath();
    const r = prompt('type x to quit').toLowerCase();
    console.log(`you typed ${r}`);
    if (r === 'x') break;
  }
}

doLoop();  //lets start the loop
```

Now in the above you can see we have used `while (true) {`, but the trick here when doing this you need to allow the event loop to run, this is what the `breath` function is doing.  The `prompt` function will still block, but those `breath`'s will just allow some time for the event loop to do it's thing.  Also notice the `async` & `await` syntax, this is what does the magic to make what looks like `sync` code actually be `async`, and as such Browser / JS friendly.

Of course even better is not using `prompt` in the first place, most GUI libs these days have features for doing dialogs, and not only do these look nicer, they will also not block the browser main event loop like `alert` / `prompt` etc do.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to do something with promises, because as you said event loop blocks and nothing goes further