# how to add object created from user input into array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I can't understand how to make an object which will be make from user input and then added to array of objects

Here is what i tired:

```
let Contact = {
    fristname: "fname",
    lastname: "lname",
}

const Contacts = []

function addContact(fristname, lastname){
    let imie = window.prompt("give fristname\n")
    let nazwisko = window.prompt("give lastname\n")
    let userObject = {};
    let userInput = prompt("Please enter some data");
    userObject.data = userInput;

}
```

Comment: btw, why do you have two parameters of `addContact`? you never use the variables. an you never call the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop for collecting data with exit and a function for adding the data into `contacts`.

The convention in Javascript is to use variables who starts with a small letter. An uppercase letter indicates a incanciable function/class and all caps indicates a constant value.

This approach takes [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for the object, where variables are taken as properties with same name.

For checking `loop` it utilises the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), because [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) could return `null` which is not a string for taking an upper case value.

```js
function addContact(firstname, lastname, data) {
    contacts.push({ firstname, lastname, data });
}

const contacts = [];

let loop;

do {
    addContact(
        prompt("give firstname"),
        prompt("give lastname"),
        prompt("Please enter some data")
    );
    loop = prompt('Another Contact? [Y/N]', 'N');
    if (loop?.toUpperCase() === 'N') loop = false;
} while (loop)

console.log(contacts);
```

Comment: How would you solve a problem which is: 
the prompt is blocking the console and i cant see it bc i have the swich in a loop

Comment: ad 2: please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71300629/window-prompt-blocks-code-execution-before-it or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77275991/prompt-executing-before-page-full-load-and-block-the-console-log

Answer (score 0):

```
    const Contacts = []

    function addContact(fristname, lastname){
        let userObject = {};
        userObject['firstname'] = window.prompt("give fristname\n");
        userObject['lastname'] = window.prompt("give lastname\n");
        userObject['data'] = prompt("Please enter some data");
        Contacts.push(userObject);
        console.log(Contacts);
    }
```

I hope this might help you.